# How to plot two histograms of different variables in one GGPlot, with legend and colours

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my first post on Stack Overflow, my first reproducible example, and I'm new to R, so please be gentle!
I am trying to display two histograms on one plot. Each histogram is a different variable (column) in my dataframe. I can't figure out how to both colour in the bars and have the legend displayed. If I use scale_fill_manual the colours are ignored, but if I use scale_colour_manual the colours are just the outlines of the  bars. If I map the colours to each histogram separately (and don't use scale_xxx_manual at all) the colours work great but I then don't get the legend.

Here is my code:

```
TwoHistos <- ggplot (cars) +
  labs(color="Variable name",x="XX",y="Count")+
  geom_histogram(aes(x=speed, color= "Speed"),  alpha = 0.2 ) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(x=dist, color= "Dist"), alpha = 0.2) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("yellow","green"))
TwoHistos
```

Here is my result in an image (I pasted it but I don't know why it isn't showing up. I'm sorry!):
[Two histograms with outlines for colours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/th0JW.png)

Comment: Hey, is there any "visual" example of what you'd like to get (web image or whatsoever)

Comment: You need to use the `fill` aesthetic instead of `color` to *fill* the bars with different colors. :) Nice going on including a reproducible code example.

Comment: Ah, I made such a rookie error! Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* (if I understand you correctly), what you might want is to give a `fill` arguement within the `geom_histogram()` call.

(I've used the `mtcars` built-in R data here as you did not give any data to work with)

```
TwoHistos <- ggplot (mtcars) +
  labs(fill="Variable name",x="XX",y="Count")+
  geom_histogram(aes(x=hp, fill= "Speed",  color = "yellow"), alpha = 0.2 ) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(x=disp, fill= "Dist", color = "green"), alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("yellow","green"))+
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("yellow","green"), guide=FALSE)
TwoHistos
```

Edit: just to make really clear that I've changed the `x` in the `geom_histogram()` so it works with `mtcars`
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it. One quick question -  how come the square for 'Dist' in the legend isn't yellow? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry...I missed that. Unfortunately I'm not able to get exactly what I want here...legends come from the `aes()` call, so that's why they're both green. I've edited the answer with one that works around this, by displaying the fill in the legend, but it doesn't have the line around the outside.

Answer (score 1):

Use `fill` instead of `color` and use `scale_fill_manual`

```
TwoHistos <- ggplot (cars) +
  labs(color="Variable name",x="XX",y="Count")+
  geom_histogram(aes(x=speed, fill= "Speed"),  alpha = 0.2 ) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(x=dist, fill= "Dist"), alpha = 0.2) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("yellow","green"))
TwoHistos
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! What a rookie error. How would I add a border of the same colour to each variable's histogram?